# class, dict, self, init, args?

Tags: python, class, arguments, self

```
class attrdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

a = attrdict(x=1, y=2)
print a.x, a.y

b = attrdict()
b.x, b.y  = 1, 2
print b.x, b.y
```

Could somebody explain the first four lines in words? I read about classes and methods. But here it seems very confusing.

Comment: this is a good way to leak memory. See http://bugs.python.org/issue1469629 for an explanation, and a better alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using positional arguments in your example. So the relevant code is:

```
class attrdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

In the first line you define class `attrdict` as a subclass of `dict`.
In the second line you define the function that automatically will initialize your instance. You pass keyword arguments (`**kargs`) to this function. When you instantiate `a`:

```
 a = attrdict(x=1, y=2)
```

you are actually calling

```
attrdict.__init__(a, {'x':1, 'y':2})
```

dict instance core initialization is done by initializing the `dict` builtin superclass. This is done in the third line passing the parameters received in  `attrdict.__init__`.
Thus,

```
dict.__init__(self,{'x':1, 'y':2})
```

makes `self` (the instance `a`) a dictionary:

```
self ==  {'x':1, 'y':2}
```

The nice thing occurs in the last line:
Each instance has a dictionary holding its attributes. This is `self.__dict__` (i.e. `a.__dict__`).

For example, if

```
a.__dict__ = {'x':1, 'y':2}
```

we could write `a.x` or `a.y` and get values 1 or 2, respectively.

So, this is what line 4 does:

```
self.__dict__ = self
```

is equivalent to:

```
a.__dict__ = a  where a = {'x':1, 'y':2}
```

Then I can call `a.x` and `a.y`.

Hope is not too messy.

Answer (score 7):

My shot at a line-by-line explanation:

```
class attrdict(dict):
```

This line declares a class attrdict as a subclass of the built-in dict class.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is your standard `__init__` method.  The call to `dict.__init__(...)` is to utilize the super
class' (in this case, dict) constructor (`__init__`) method.

The final line, `self.__dict__ = self` makes it so the keyword-arguments (kwargs) you pass to the `__init__` method can be accessed like attributes, i.e., a.x, a.y in the code below.

Hope this helps clear up your confusion.

Comment: Need to fix the `__init__`. Put backticks around them, and they will look like my `__init__`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a good article that explains `__dict__`:

[The Dynamic **dict**](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#the-dynamic-dict)

The `attrdict` class exploits that by inheriting from a dictionary and then setting the object's `__dict__` to that dictionary.  So any attribute access occurs against the parent dictionary (i.e. the `dict` class it inherits from).

The rest of the article is quite good too for understanding Python objects:

[Python Attributes and Methods](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html)