# python getattr and setattr with self.__dict__

Tags: python

I have been reading about overriding getattr and setattr and I can't figure out if I need the overriding assignments if I use self.__dict__ = self in the constructor.

Once I make an instance of the class

```
a = OPT(foo='bar')
```

a.foo and a['foo'] work with and without the __getattr__ and __setattr__ declaration.

Can someone explain if I need both. If I do, why?  Thanks!

```
class OPT(dict):
    __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OPT, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

Comment: Setting `self.__dict__ = self` is probably not a good idea.  What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: I am accessing the class as an obj or like a dict.  so I can do a['bar'] or a.bar.  Like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641484/class-dict-self-init-args)

Comment: The problem is if someone does `a['keys'] = 2`, they will stomp on the `keys()` method of the dict, and so on.

Comment: ha, I did not think of that.  I've seen this implementation before. There are a lot of posts about it but I don't remember that issue coming up.

Comment: @BrenBarn's comment is really the answer here.

Comment: Be careful! - __ getattr __ = dict.__ getitem __ - will raise "KeyError" instead of "AttributeError" required by API docs: docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__ Instead use this: def __ getattr __: if key in self: return self[key] else: raise AttributeError(key)

Answer (score 2):

You override getattr and setattr when you want to do something extra when the class user gets or sets an attribute. For example:

1) you might avoid raising an exception when user manipulates an invalid attribute, so you just return None for an unknown attribute.

2) attribute manipulations are actually forwarded/delegated, so the valid attributes are not known in advance e.g. a class that represents a database row and the user manipulates columns as attributes. I need to run-time check if the given attribute name matches column name, and perhaps I'd like to forgive upper-case/lower-case differences etc.

Another thing, containment is sometimes preferred to subclassing. Instead of inheriting from a dict, you could create a class that contains a dict.

Comment: If I don't plan on doing anything like that I wouldn't need to override getattr and setattr?  I could always pass in a default value for .get() in your first example.  I don't know what an example of your 2nd point would be.

Comment: Edited the second example for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class DotDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, d: dict = {}):
        super().__init__()
        for key, value in d.items():
            self[key] = DotDict(value) if type(value) is dict else value
    
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            return self[key]
        raise AttributeError(key) #Set proper exception, not KeyError

    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
```

Comment: In `__init__` you should use `d: dict=None` as the default argument value instead of `d: dict={}`. Default argument values are evaluated only once (at module load time) and are shared by all the calls to the function (here `__init__`), which may result in "extremely surprising behavior" (see Brett Slatkin's *Effective Python, 2nd ed*., "Item 24: Use `None` and Docstrings to Specify Dynamic Default Arguments")

Comment: You should make sure that `d` is not `None` before iterating over `d.items()`

Comment: @KiriSakow, the issue you point out doesn't happen with default values as objects. I tried this code with no issues in console:
y = DotDict({"d": "ha!"})
y.c = "ok"
print(y)

x = DotDict()
x.c = "ok"
print(x)

#{'d': 'ha!', 'c': 'ok'}
#{'c': 'ok'}

Comment: It normally does happen — in both functions and constructors. Unless you want to memoize, do not use empty literals as default values, use `None`. See Brett Slatkin's book for an example, or this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692179/init-method-gets-a-value-while-none-is-passed/41692265#41692265

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more elaborate fork of the Marquinho Peli's answer. Changes: support for dictionaries with nested lists;

```py
class DotDict(dict):
    """A dictionary that's recursively navigable with dots, not brackets."""

    def __init__(self, data: dict = None):
        super().__init__()
        if data is None or not isinstance(data, dict):
            raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__} must be instantiated with a dictionary, not a {type(data).__name__}.")
        for key, value in data.items():
            if isinstance(value, list):
                self[key] = [DotDict(item) for item in value]
            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                self[key] = DotDict(value)
            else:
                self[key] = value

    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(f"attribute .{key} not found")
```

Usage examples:

```py
d = {'key1': 'value1',
     'key2': 'value2',
     'key3': {'key3a': 'value3a'},
     'key4': {'key4a': [{'key4aa': 'value4aa',
                         'key4ab': 'value4ab',
                         'key4ac': 'value4ac'}],
              'key4b': 'value4b'}}

dd = DotDict(d)
print(dd.key4.key4a[0].key4aa)  # value4aa
dd.key4.key4a[0].key4aa = 'newval'
print(dd.key4.key4a[0].key4aa)  # newval

print(dd.key4.key4a[0].key4aaa) # AttributeError: attribute .key4aaa not found

DotDict({}) # OK
DotDict()   # AttributeError: DotDict must be instantiated with dictionary, not a NoneType.
```