# __init__ method gets a value while none is passed

Tags: python, default, init

I have a class `TextBuffer`. It has an `__init__` function which can be used to pass an initial value for the content of `TextBuffer`. If no value is passed, then it should use an empty list as default value.

The class has a method **add**, in order to add text to the TextBuffer:

```
a = TextBuffer()
a += "TEXT"
```

For some reason, calling the `__init__` method without parameters does not use the default value of `[]` for `lst`, but a previously added value to another instance of `TextBuffer`, which is not in the `__init__` call

```
a = TextBuffer()
a += "BUFFER A"
b = TextBuffer()  ### lst in the __init__ call has the value of ["BUFFER A"]
b += "BUFFER B"
```

I have no idea why this happens. Maybe I'm doing something wrong in the `__add__` method?

Please consider the complete example code:

```
import pprint

### Two functions for byte/string conversion in Python3
def b(x):
    if ( type(x) == type(b'')):
        return x
    else:
        return x.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
def s(x):
    if ( type(x) == type(b'') ):
        return x.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
    else:
        return x


class TextBuffer():
    def __init__( self, lst = [], maxlines = None ):
        self.content = []
        if ( type(lst) == type([])):
            if (len(lst) > 0):
                print("INIT got a nonempty lst value:")
                pprint.pprint(lst)
                print("------------------------------")
            self.content = lst


    def __getitem__( self, i ):
        try:
            return self.content[i]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def __iter__( self ):
        for line in self.content:
            yield line

    def __contains__( self, item ):
        return item in self.content

    def __len__( self ):
        return len(self.content)

    def __add__( self, item ):
        self.content.append(item)
        return self

    def __radd__( self, item ):
        return self.__add__(item)

    def __repr__( self ):
        result = ""
        for line in self.content:
            if ( type(line) == type(b"") ):
                result+=s(line)
            else:
                result+=line
        return result

    def __str__( self ):
        return repr(self)

    def __unicode__( self ):
        return repr(self.content)

### TextBuffer INIT with empty list creates an empty textbuffer
a = TextBuffer(lst=[])
print("a = TextBuffer(lst=[])")

a += "BUFFER A"


### TextBuffer INIT with empty list creates an empty textbuffer
b = TextBuffer(lst=[])
print("b = TextBuffer(lst=[])")

b += "BUFFER B"

print("Content of TextBuffer a:")
print(a)
print("Content of TextBuffer b:")
print(b)

print("-------------------------")

### TextBuffer INIT without any parameters should use default value for lst of []
### So an empty list. Should be the same as TextBuffer(lst=[])
a = TextBuffer()
print("a = TextBuffer()")

a += "BUFFER A"

### TextBuffer INIT without any parameters should use default value for lst of []
### So an empty list. Should be the same as TextBuffer(lst=[])
### But now, the value of lst is not [], it is the string added to TextBuffer 'a': ['BUFFER A']
b = TextBuffer()
print("b = TextBuffer()")

b += "BUFFER B"

print("Content of TextBuffer a:")
print(a)
print("Content of TextBuffer b:")
print(b)
```

Comment: Because you have a mutable thing as the default argument (`[]`). All instances share _that_ list, so if one of them adds an item to it, they all have that added. This is a duplicate of many questions.

Comment: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#default-parameter-values

Comment: There _are_ situations where you can safely use a default mutable argument, this is not one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `lst = []` **as default argument** in this case, since Python will **makes one list** in memory and passes each time **a reference to the same object (list)** to the constructor. This means that your two objects share the same `lst` and thus modifications made by one object are reflected in the other and vice versa.

You can use the following trick:

```
def __init__( self, lst = None, maxlines = None ):
    if lst is None:
        lst = []
    #... (remainder of the constructor)
```

since here you force Python **to construct a new list**. Evidently you could use another value than `None`; but I think for your case this will be sufficient.

In general it is a good idea to *not* feed *mutable* objects as default values, always use immutable objects. There are however, as @hiroprotagonist describes cases where this behavior is wanted (like memoization), but I would advice to be very careful with these.

Comment: you *can* use a mutable type as default argument. if you know what you are doing it may be a good idea (e.g. meomize).

Comment: when is the list passed to the instace? while loading the module or when calling the `__init__` mehtod?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist yes, but generally that's not what you want to do.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: yeah you are right, my point was merely that for the scenario the OP describes, this is not a good idea. I softened my claim.

Comment: @DanielSanchez: well each time you call the constructor with default value, the reference is passed (if you would feed `lst` another list, evidently the other list will be used).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: i agree. hence the 'if you know what you are doing'-part.