# How do I define a class where the arguments given to it on instantiation becomes its instance variables?

Tags: python, attributes, instantiation

I want to create a class where the attributes of its instance are defined at instantiation.

At first I thought I should do something like this,

```
class TestData(object):  # Example via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641484/class-dict-self-init-args

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestData, self).__init__()
        for arg in args:
            self.arg = arg
```

but that would assign all arguments to the same attribute `self.arg` and that wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Modified with suggestions from comments, I came to this solution which works for me:

```
class TestData(object):  # Example via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641484/class-dict-self-init-args

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestData, self).__init__()
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        for arg in args:
            setattr(self, arg, arg)
```

and if further attributes need to be added subsequent to instantiation, that can be done by calling `setattr(instancename, arg, val)`

Comment: Now I'd like to find out how to define a class method to call which would easily print out all the attributes.

Comment: There is no need to call `__setattr__` in either case. Generally you should avoid calling the double-underscore magic methods directly. Just do `setattr(self, arg, arg)`.

Comment: instead of overwriting the __dict__ it's better to update it: `self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)`.